# Powerpoint Number Counter on the slide master that continues across everyslide

Tags: numbers, powerpoint, counter

What I'm trying to achieve in MS Powerpoint is a number counter that counts up to a predtermind number i.e. from 1 to 1000 over a number of slides and if the number is reached before the end of the slide show due to an over run, it will just show 1000 on the slide(s) that the talk has over run on.

So far I have found some code that counts down from 60 to 0 but only on one slide, and i'm trying to us this as basis but so far having no luck due to my lack of VBA & powerpoint understanding.

Any Help Would Be greatly Appriceated.

Here is the count down code that works on just one slide below:

```
Sub Time_Me2()
Dim oshp As Shape
 Dim oshpRng As ShapeRange
 Dim osld As Slide
 Dim oeff As Effect
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim Iduration As Integer
 Dim Istep As Integer
 Dim texttoshow As String
 On Error GoTo errhandler
 If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count > 1 Then
 MsgBox "Please just select ONE shape!"
 Exit Sub
 End If
 Set osld = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange (1)
 Set oshp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

  oshp.Copy

 'change to suit
 Istep = 1
 Iduration = 60 'in seconds

 For i = Iduration To 0 Step -Istep
 Set oshpRng = osld.Shapes.Paste
 With oshpRng
 .Left = oshp.Left
 .Top = oshp.Top
 End With
 texttoshow = CStr(i)
 oshpRng(1).TextFrame.TextRange = texttoshow
 Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence _
 .AddEffect(oshpRng(1), msoAnimEffectFlashOnce, , msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious)
 oeff.Timing.Duration = Istep
 Next i
 oshp.Delete
 Exit Sub
errhandler:
 MsgBox Err.Description
 End Sub
```

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that you add a text box or other shape, formatted the way you want it, on Slide 1 and select it before running the code.  Also, edit it to set lMaxCount to 1000 or whatever number you'd like it to "stick" at.

```
Sub NumberSlides()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oOriginalShape As Shape
    Dim x As Long
    Dim lMaxCount As Long

    ' edit to suit
    lMaxCount = 5

    ' is something selected?
    If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
        MsgBox "Please select one and only one shape on Slide 1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' is only ONE shape selected?
    If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select one and only one shape on Slide 1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' is the selected shape on the first slide?
    If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Parent.SlideIndex = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select one and only one shape on Slide 1"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set oOriginalShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    For x = 2 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(x)
        oOriginalShape.Copy
        Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.Paste(1)
        If x > lMaxCount Then
            oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CStr(lMaxCount)
        Else
            oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CStr(x)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```